# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 - react-native

Tags: react-native

[SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1uac.png)

tried this:

android studio> sync with gradle files>clean project

```
yarn start —- –-reset-cache
```

run project on android studio

IT WORKED!

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

check your JSX code, you may have < before/after a JSX tag, which leads to that error

eg:

```
<<View>
     <Text>Something</Text>
   </View>
```